# Classification trees: favor one classification over other

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, cart

We're using classification trees (c50 package) for a BUY/WAIT advice. However, the advice in our training set is not well balanced. That is, we advice to buy 3/4 times more than to wait. 
Probably as a result, the confusion matrix of the tree scores very well on the BUY advice, but not so good the WAIT advice. ( 90+ % percent on buy, < 1 % on WAIT )

My question: how can we train the tree in a way that a misclassification of one category is penalized heavier than the other?

So we sacrifice accuracy of the BUY advice ( and probably overall accuracy ) but score better on WAIT.

```
// The Advice holds the calculated advice - the
// advice we want to give
> table(testdata$Advice)

  BUY   WAIT 
217745  74737

// After training the tree and running the test
// set - these are the numbers of the predicted values
> table(prediction)
prediction
  BUY   WAIT 
292039    443

// So the confusion matrix looks as follows
> table(prediction,testdata$Advice)

prediction    BUY   WAIT
     BUY  217499  74540
     WAIT    246    197
```

Other example: let's say we're classifying tumors. Surely you would rather misclassify a non-malignant tumor to be malignant ( and find out later that everything is OK ), than misclassify a malignant to be non-malignant.

Comment: Yes, you can use weights. How to specify them depends on the package you are using. In the tree package you can use the weights argument. Perhaps the more difficult question is what the "correct" value for the weights should be to provide an "appropriate" cost for incorrect classifications.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I found the `weights` parameter - I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you balance the training data set? I think the issue is that your data are unbalanced. So the  classifier 'prefers' to be more accurate on major class than on minor one. You should balance data before training. 
There are 2 ways:

1. increase number of records of minor class
2. decrease number of records of major class

Each has its drawbacks. Which one works better in your choice you can check experimentally.
There is also approaches to do weighted training but I'm not sure if R has such function.

Comment: No we didn't. The trainingset is not balanced. We discussed the option, but thought that messing with the distribution of training data ( removing entries from only 1 of the categories, as you suggested ) would result in a non-representative tree. But thanks - we'll give it a try. And - as @shane mentioned - weights is indeed possible too.